# Creating the modern 'single page' html5 css3 layout in wordpress

Tags: theme-development

I am considering to develop a new portfolio website in the form of a single page website. I do not know if this is a new concept, but I see it becoming popular for portfolio websites, it is also quite a handy form.

Now I want to create the about, portfolio, contact on one page, and have a normal blog on another page. So actually there is one single page, and one blog page.

To give you an example of the single page, here is a link to a tutorial that creates such a single page. But this is just a normal static page.

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/html5-css3-website-template/

Now is the best way to go about this to just create a single page, and have all my content displayed there just formatted in one big pile of html.
Or is there a more elegant solution to do this. Maybe with several custom post types on a single page, or is this not possible or not efficient.

*I am pretty new to wordpress, sorry for if this is a stupid Q*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's how I would set things up, not necessarily the correct / best / only way.

- create a home page, blog page, about page, contact page, etc.. as individual pages.
- create a custom post type for my portfolio items.
- use posts as the blog posts.
- set static front page to my home page, blog page as the posts page.
- create a front-page.php template, this will load whatever content I have in home by default.
- use [get_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) and [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to load all of my pages and portfolio items into the template.
- use a caching plugin to make it all nice and speedy

Comment: +1 wow this is great. Didn't think of it this way at all, and it will be quite easy for me. I have already set up separate pages etc and having portfolio items as custom post types. Only thing I then have to do i creating the front page and just pull everything in. GREAT!! Accepting answer soon.